# Proving convergence in the operator norm in $l^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider the following linear map from $l^{2}$ to $l^{2}$:

$T(x)_{n} = \frac{x_{n}}{n}$

I know that this operator is the pointwise limit of the operators $T_{n}$ that output $(x_{1}, \dots, \frac{x_{n}}{n}, 0, 0, \dots)$. How do I show that $||T-T_{n}|| \to 0$, where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm on $l^{2}$, defined by 
$$ 
||T|| = \sup_{||x||=1} ||T(x)||
$$
I'm struggling with showing that the convergence is uniform on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...)$, we have $|x_{k}|\leq\|x\|_{2}$, $k=1,2,...$, so
\begin{align*}
\|(T-T_{n})x\|_{2}&=\left(\sum_{k\geq n+1}\dfrac{x_{k}^{2}}{k^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{k\geq n+1}\dfrac{\|x\|_{2}^{2}}{k^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\|x\|_{2}\left(\sum_{k\geq n+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\right)^{1/2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|T-T_{n}\|\leq\left(\sum_{k\geq n+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}